# stress tolerant router

Tags: router

Searching for a router, maybe a router/DSL modem hybrid that is a bit robust.
I don´t care about speed; anything on the current market will suffice; but I´d like something that can take a few bumps without getting bruised.

I´m not talking about outdoor computing or industry requirements, although the [Siemens Ruggedcom](http://w3.siemens.com/mcms/industrial-communication/en/rugged-communication/products/switches-routers-layer-3/Pages/cellular-router.aspx) look like fine pieces of engineering. Does anybody have experience with these? Does the 1400 also have DSL connectivity? And what do they cost (in germany, if you can tell)?

---

I want a router that can take some changes in weather, voltage, amperage and will last a few years with all the network roadworks that go on these days (and will surely not subside). I.e.:

- capacitors should have a good deal of tolerance to power surges
- components should not be too tightly packed (good heat dissipation)
- should not require active cooling

additional requirements:

- MAC filter is a must-have
- should have no problems to handle up to a dozen WLAN devices
- Are there any routers for home/office use that allow taking a look at their innards?

nice to have (not required, but please mention if your recommended device has it)

- VPN support: very nice
- USB slot: nice (for a printer or network drive)
- SIM slot: luxury

Comment: Have you considered getting a UPS?  (Uninterruptable Power Source) This will shield any device behind it from power fluctuation, and if they get to bad it will run on battery for a few minutes until the condition improve.

Comment: @cybernard: I already got a shielding power plug, now also plugged the ethernet cable through it.But thanks for the idea; it will be a first step for my colleagues.